# Como hago para validar las opciones "Check for Directory and File Permissions" en dotProject

Tags: php

Un saludo, quisiera que me ayudaran ya que deseo instalar dotProject y como requerimiento se necesita que todas la opciones del punto **"Check for Directory and File Permissions"** esten validadas, y en el caso mio no lo estan, la pregunta es como puedo solucionar esto, como puedo habilitar o dejar validadas estas opciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar los permisos de las carpetas que te sugiere dotProject

> ./files writable?
>
> ./files/temp writable?
>
> ./locales/en writable?

Si estas en linux, deberías colocar los permisos a esas carpetas en 777, o lo que son permisos de lectura, escritura y ejecución.

En linux a través de chmod seria:

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/dotproject/files
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/dotproject/files/temp
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/dotproject/locales
```

Comment: En que carpeta o archivo??

Comment: he realizado lo que me has indicado pero en la instalacion se recomienda que no se debe presentar este mensaje en cada unos de los directorios **World Writable** , aunque en el primero ya no se sigue presentando, puedes ver la imagen que agregue en la pregunta principal @Juan Pinzón

Comment: Intenta colocándole permisos 755

Comment: Intente colocando permisos 755 pero ya se presenta otro mensaje ** File upload functionality will be disabled** para la carpeta seleccionada @Juan Pinzón

Comment: En que carpeta?

Comment: Este fue el comando para la carpeta files  `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/dotproject/files` @Juan Pinzón

Comment: Ponle 755, esta 775

Comment: Perdon utilice fue 755, pero se sigue presentando el problema @Juan Pinzón

Comment: Dejala en 777, donde piensas usar dotproject? solo para ti o piensas ponerlo en produccion?

Comment: Hasta el momento para mi, depronto a futuro podria utilizarlo en produccion que me recomiendas ya que el manual que estoy siguiendo me indica esto **En la parte de “Checkfor Directory and File Permissions” también deben estar
todas las opciones validadas y si a la derecha de alguna de ellas nos aparece
la frase “World Writable” se deberá revisar y ampliar los niveles de
permisología sobre el directorio indicado** @Juan Pinzón,

Comment: Realmente esa advertencia lo que te dice es que otros usuarios también pueden escribir en esa carpeta(World Writable = Permiso Goblal), sin embargo como solo piensas usarlo para ti, no creo que haya problemas de seguridad.

Comment: Pues por ahora sera trabajar asi, pero estaria bien saber cual es el el permiso necesario para esta carpeta , muchas gracias @Juan Pinzón

Answer (score 1):

No conozco dotProject, y la respuesta de Juan Pinzón es válida hasta cierto punto, la documentación de dotProject y su mismo código fuente sugieren no hacer los archivos "World writable", o sea con permisos 777:

https://github.com/BigBlueHat/dotproject/blob/master/dotproject/install/vw_idx_check.php

```
<tr>
        <td class="title" colspan="2"><br />Check for Directory and File Permissions</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td class="item" colspan="2">If the message 'World Writable' appears after a file/directory, then Permissions for this File have been set to allow all users to write to this file/directory.
        Consider changing this to a more restrictive setting to improve security. You will need to do this manually.</td>
</tr>
<?php
$okMessage='';
if ((file_exists($cfgFile) && !is_writable($cfgFile)) || (!file_exists($cfgFile) && !(is_writable($cfgDir)))) {
    @chmod($cfgFile, $chmod);
    @chmod($cfgDir, $chmod);
    $filemode = @fileperms($cfgFile);
    if ($filemode & 2) {
        $okMessage='<span class="error"> World Writable</span>';
    }
}
?>
<tr>
        <td class="item">./includes/config.php writable?</td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo (is_writable($cfgFile) || is_writable($cfgDir))  ? '<b class="ok">'.$okImg.'</b>'.$okMessage : '<b class="error">'.$failedImg.'</b><span class="warning"> Configuration process can still be continued. Configuration file will be displayed at the end, just copy & paste this and upload.</span>';?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$okMessage="";
if (!is_writable($filesDir)) {
    @chmod($filesDir, $chmod);
}
$filemode = @fileperms($filesDir);
if ($filemode & 2) {
    $okMessage='<span class="error"> World Writable</span>';
}
?>
<tr>
        <td class="item">./files writable?</td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo is_writable($filesDir) ? '<b class="ok">'.$okImg.'</b>'.$okMessage : '<b class="error">'.$failedImg.'</b><span class="warning"> File upload functionality will be disabled</span>';?></td>
</tr>
```

Hay una pequeña discusión sobre permisos en el Foro de dotProject:
http://dotproject.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=7711

La sugerencia es 750 para directorios y 640 para archivos y el usuario del servidor web debería ser el "dueño" de dichos directorios y archivos (usuarios: apache, www-data, etc... según el caso). Asumiendo que tu proveedor de hosting no sea muy bueno que digamos, no tendrías más opción que usar 777.